# How to read in a text file from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to read in a log file created by a SSIS package in my stored procedure.

Is there a good way to do this?

I tried using [this code](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) but it shows the contents of my file as jibberish.  Is there some kind of encoding issue it's not handling?  Is there an easier way?

Comment: When you say text file do you mean a .txt file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried a straight bulk insert?  For example:

```
create table #TempTable (line varchar(256))
bulk insert #TempTable from 'c:\logfile.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
select * from OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\logfile.txt', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

Comment: That gives me back a long string of numbers (hexadecimal without spaces maybe?)

Comment: It reads the whole file as a single blob. Whaddya expect? :) Then you can splice it and dice it with all kinds of string manipulation functions if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedures doing File Manipulation doesnt sound like a good idea!

Maybe you can explain the scenario in more detail that might help people suggest maybe a better way out.

However, if you HAVE TO, i think you should look at CLR Stored Procedures in SQL Server.
That way, you can do the file manipulation using regular .NET classes

Refer these [MSDN Link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(VS.80).aspx) and [MSDN Link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) links for more details

This particular [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx) is related to permissions that need to be given to the assembly for it to be able to access external resources like files from a CLR procedure in SQL Server