# Stored proc to delete 6 days old data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my stored proc

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[mtk_sp_Deletion]as
begin
   delete from tbl1
   where DateModified< getdate() - 6

   delete tbl2
   where DateModified < getdate() - 6

   delete tbl3
   where DateModified < getdate() - 6
end
```

RIGHT NOW I just hard code the value "6" but I want to achieve like read the text file (the text file contains this value eg: 6 or 10 or 12), and get the value pass it here to delete.

Please some one help me how to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the value as a parameter:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[mtk_sp_Deletion](
  @nDays int = 6
)
as

begin
   delete from tbl1
   where DateModified< getdate() - @nDays

   delete tbl2
   where DateModified < getdate() - @nDays

   delete tbl3
   where DateModified < getdate() - @nDays

end
```

If you want to read that value from a textfile, do a search on SO and you will get lots of answers, e.g.: [How to read in a text file from a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659423/how-to-read-in-a-text-file-from-a-stored-procedure)